# How I can use a Bootstrap Modal Dialog and get the return values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I want to create a Modal Dialog with Bootstrap. I am new in Bootstrap.

how this:

[image]

How I can do this and how I get the values from the textfield back.

Comment: The best way will be to start reading the docs of [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Are you using ASP.NET or PHP?

Comment: I want use javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modal is on the same page. So whatever input field you have inside modal is accessible in your page.

For example you have

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
```

You can simply access it using

```
$("#txtName").val();
```

for Modal code. Here it is done

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="text" id="txtname">
    </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var name = $('#txtname').val();
```

for access value from dropdownlist:

You'd have something like:

```
var plantid = $('.drpplants').get(0).value;
```

Or

```
var plantid = $('.drpplants').get(1).value;
```